# List Microsoft Sharepoint Sites with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working with Microsoft OneDrive and Microsoft Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph, and as I understood:

Url to get file list from logged in user *OneDrive* is:

`/v1.0/me/drive/root/children`

Url to get file list from company *Sharepoint Documents* is:

`/v1.0/drive/root/children`

---

So my questing is:

How to list *Sharepoint Sites* that user is following and upload files to this *Sites*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible yet. You need to use the direct SharePoint API end point to access content from SharePoint Sites.

Graph API supports accessing OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and the document library for an Office 365 Group only.

Comment: is it still the case, more than one year later ?

Comment: The Microsoft Graph beta end point makes it possible to address files in SharePoint sites: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/baseitem_getbyurl