# Fetch all sites from SharePoint by Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Does anyone know how I can fetch all sites from my SharePoint by using Microsoft Graph API?

I saw this documents but it seemed that there are no API to list sites.

And I saw this questions but answer was there were no ways.
[List Microsoft Sharepoint Sites with Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952186/list-microsoft-sharepoint-sites-with-microsoft-graph)

Could you help me?

Comment: Could you please try GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=* and see if it helps?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the answer ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Graph API supported to get all SharePoint sites:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

You can test in Graph Explorer firstly:

[image]

Reference:

[Retrieve Site Collections And SubSites Using Microsoft Graph API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-site-collections-and-subsites-using-microsoft-graph-api/)